# What is "index should be positive integer(not complex format integer)" in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

```
// I made function like this:
function y = ZL(L,f)
if isvector(f)
    y=1j*2*pi.*f*L;
else
    y=1j*2*pi.*f*L;
end
```

// and command :
    L = 10,
    f= -10000:100:10000,
    ZL=ZL(L,f);

```
// then error : 
index should be positive integer(not complex format integer) or boolean
-> this error is translated by me who is Korean; sorry

what's wrong with it?
```

Comment: This works without error for me, what Matlab version are you using?

Comment: 2014...;; there is no error??? In this time, New error : index exceed dimension of matrix. what is that?

Comment: Same here in Matlab 8 this works fine. Another question i have is: why do you use the if, else structure. Since both comands are identical. Also i added another <end> since you need one <end> for terminating the if-else structure and one <end> for ending the function

Comment: Ah, on a second look your problem is that you name both the function and the result `ZL`. Change that e.g. `ZL_output = ZL(L,f)`. Also try `which ZL -all` to get some insight...

Comment: Thank you all of you guys^^;

Answer (score 3):

First time you call `ZL = ZL(L,f)`, you don't get any error.

If you try to call your command a second time, you'll get this error: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions`. It's because you affect the variable `ZL`, so the second time it's not the function you're calling but you"re trying to get elements from the array `ZL`.

So please don't use same name for a variable and an existing function, otherwise the function name is masked by the variable.

Comment: I think everyone has already once made this kind of mistake ... it's the best way to learn and remember it! :)